# moment.js endDate plus 1 month

Tags: javascript, angularjs, momentjs

I can't for the life of me understand this warning. And I can't get my date to add 1 month to endDate. Please help! I am trying to set default date plus 1 month to endDate. I am new to angular and moment.

```
  function recursiveCategory(categoryToMarkAsRecrusive) {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    var category = new Category();

    var startDate = new Date();
    var endDate = moment().add(30, 'days');

    category.id = categoryToMarkAsRecrusive.id;

    category.set('isRecursive', categoryToMarkAsRecrusive.recursive);
    category.set('startDate', startDate);
    category.set('endDate', endDate);

    category.save().then(function(recursiveCategory){
        deferred.resolve(recursiveCategory);
    }, function(error) {
        deferred.reject(error);
    });

    return deferred.promise;
}
```

and the error is this:

> angular.js:14700 Possibly unhandled rejection:
>   {"code":100,"message":"XMLHttpRequest failed: {}"}

Comment: Possibly unhandled rejection seems not due to your endDate, have you attempt to find other errors? Let's check have `category.save()` run and what's inside this function

Comment: hmm, no not a first. but now i see that Parse and moment are not defined in jslint.. How do you import modules in angular!! require and import aren't allowing me to define them even though they have been added to my vendor.js scripts. like so:                                                                        
 <script src="bower_components/moment/moment.js"></script> not sure if this is even it tho. thanks @StanleyCheung. I am using   "angular": "^1.4.0",

Comment: Are you using [anguler-moment](https://github.com/urish/angular-moment) ? You need to do something like this > `var myapp = angular.module('myapp', ['angularMoment']);`  to use the package

Comment: thanks @StanleyCheung I am using angular-moment... still same issue :(